# put display none on divs of similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs one after anothr.. actually 10 of these. 
I want a jquery solution such that it goes through the divs and whenever it finds any images that are similar , the whole div is not displayed or aka display:none is inserted in the css class. Similar divs can only stay adjacent to each other only according to the logic I have in my code. as in below

```
<div class="tops">

<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/AxlRose.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">Axl<br>Roses</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/AxlRose.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">Axl<br>Roses</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/Eminem.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">Eminem</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/Eminem.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">Eminem</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/artistA.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">artistA</p>
</div>



<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/artistA.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">artistB</p>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/artistA.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">artistA</p>
</div>



<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/artistG.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">artistG</p>
</div>



<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/artistH.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">artistH</p>
</div>



<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/artistI.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">artistI</p>
</div>

</div>
```

**Also, no  more than 5 div will be displayed. ANd if there are less than 5 divs after putting the display:none, then 5 divs will be displayed anyway aka last few display:none will not be there so that 5 divs are always displayed.**

A jquery solution will be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "images that are similar"?

Comment: Exactly, +1 @Evan, the only way you would know that the images are similar is if the url is the same, or some crazy image processing you probably dont want to get involved with.

Comment: basically following divs are similar since the URL are the same. We do not need to go and do image processing. Just look at the file name. <div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/AxlRose.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">Axl<br>Roses</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 topleaderBoardSB">
<p class="smallImages"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="32399/images/pics/AxlRose.png"> </p>
<p class="smallText">Axl<br>Roses</p>
</div>

Comment: It seems to me that your real requirement is to define a test for "similar" that can be applied to the *src* property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
var images = [],
    img,
    count = 0;

$("img").filter(function(){
    img = $(this).attr("src");

    if($.inArray(img, images) < 0 && count < 5){
        images.push(img);
        count++;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}).closest($('div')).hide();
```

The way this works is that it basically grabs all the `img` tags on the page, then filters them based on whether or not their `src` attribute is unique.  If it isn't, then it finds the parent `div` and hides it.

This is a little less-than-optimal because of `$.inArray`, so you could tweak that if it matters to you.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhnav/1/)

**EDIT: Now updated to limit to 5 results only.**

Comment: You can use `var images = document.images` since the [images collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-images) exists by default in all browsers.

Comment: Neat @RobG - didn't know about that. A similar concept would apply in that case too.

Answer (score 0):

A plain JS solution is:

```
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  el = el && el.parentNode;
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  for ( ;el; el = el.parentNode) {
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function hideSimilarImages() {
  var image, images = document.images;
  var sources = {};
  var div;

  for (var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    image = images[i]

    if (image.src in sources) {
      div = upTo(image, 'div');

      if (div && div.style) div.style.display = 'none';

    } else {
      sources[image.src] = '';
    }
  } 
}
```

#### Edit

If you want to limit the number of images display, pass a value to the function and apply it when determining whether to hide the div or not:

```
function hideSimilarImages(limit) {
  var image, images = document.images;
  var sources = {};
  var count = 0;
  var div;

  limit = typeof limit == 'undefined'? Infinity : --limit;

  for (var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    image = images[i]

    if (image.src in sources || count > limit) {
      div = upTo(image, 'div');

      if (div && div.style) div.style.display = 'none';

    } else {
      sources[image.src] = '';
      ++count;
    }
  } 
}
```

If the function isn't passed a value, it will show all unique images. Otherwise it will only show images up to the limit. If `0` is passed, it won't show any.